# NullPointerException when using GMapsV2Direction

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I've been trying to fix this run-time error for the last few days to no avail, not sure why it's throwing a NullPointerException when it creates the NodeList when the getDirection method is called. Judging by the debugger the LatLng co-ordinates and the direction type is being passed through the getDocument() method, but a document isn't being returned from the getDocument() method.

```
public Document getDocument(LatLng start, LatLng end, String mode) {
    String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?" 
            + "origin=" + start.latitude + "," + start.longitude  
            + "&destination=" + end.latitude + "," + end.longitude 
            + "&sensor=false&units=metric&mode=driving";

    try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
        InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
        DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(in);
        return doc;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public ArrayList<LatLng> getDirection (Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1, nl2, nl3, nl4;
    ArrayList<LatLng> listGeopoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    double time=0;
    nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("step");
    if (nl1.getLength() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nl1.getLength(); i++) {
        double t=0;
            Node node1 = nl1.item(i);
            nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();

            Node locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "start_location"));
            nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
            Node latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lat"));
            double lat = Double.parseDouble(latNode.getTextContent());
            Node lngNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lng"));
            double lng = Double.parseDouble(lngNode.getTextContent());
            listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));

            locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "polyline"));
            nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
            latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "points"));
            ArrayList<LatLng> arr = decodePoly(latNode.getTextContent());
            for(int j = 0 ; j < arr.size() ; j++) {
                listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(arr.get(j).latitude, arr.get(j).longitude));
            }

            locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "end_location"));
            nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
            latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lat"));
            lat = Double.parseDouble(latNode.getTextContent());
            lngNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lng"));
            lng = Double.parseDouble(lngNode.getTextContent());
            listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));


            locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "duration"));
            nl4 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
            Node node2 = nl4.item(getNodeIndex(nl4, "value"));
            t = Double.parseDouble(node2.getTextContent());
            time=time+t;
        }
        Log.i("duration", String.valueOf(time));
    }

    return listGeopoints;
}
```

Here is the function I'm using to call the getDirection method:

```
public void onClick_GetDirections(View v){
MyGPSToolDirections md = new MyGPSToolDirections();

LatLng fromPosition = new LatLng(13.68714, 100.53525);
LatLng toPosition = new LatLng(13.68366, 100.53900);

Document doc1 = md.getDocument(fromPosition, toPosition,     MyGPSToolDirections.MODE_DRIVING);

ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoint = md.getDirection(doc1);
PolylineOptions rectLine = new PolylineOptions().width(3).color(Color.RED);

for(int i = 0 ; i < directionPoint.size() ; i++) {          
rectLine.add(directionPoint.get(i));

GPSToolMap.addPolyline(rectLine);
}
```

Stack trace:

```
08-07 17:14:31.682: E/AndroidRuntime(2201): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-07 17:14:31.682: E/AndroidRuntime(2201): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
08-07 17:14:31.682: E/AndroidRuntime(2201):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3599)
08-07 17:14:31.682: E/AndroidRuntime(2201):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
08-07 17:14:31.682: E/AndroidRuntime(2201):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
08-07 17:14:31.682: E/AndroidRuntime(2201):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
08-07 17:14:31.682: E/AndroidRuntime(2201):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-07 17:14:31.682: E/AndroidRuntime(2201):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-07 17:14:31.682: E/AndroidRuntime(2201):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-07 17:14:31.682: E/AndroidRuntime(2201):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-07 17:14:31.682: E/AndroidRuntime(2201):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-07 17:14:31.682: E/AndroidRuntime(2201):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-07 17:14:31.682: E/AndroidRuntime(2201):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-07 17:14:31.682: E/AndroidRuntime(2201):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-07 17:14:31.682: E/AndroidRuntime(2201): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08-07 17:14:31.682: E/AndroidRuntime(2201):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-07 17:14:31.682: E/AndroidRuntime(2201):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08 -07 17:14:31.682: E/AndroidRuntime(2201):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3594)
08-07 17:14:31.682: E/AndroidRuntime(2201):     ... 11 more
08-07 17:14:31.682: E/AndroidRuntime(2201): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-07 17:14:31.682: E/AndroidRuntime(2201):     at com.L00081183.mygpstool.MyGPSToolDirections.getDirection(MyGPSToolDirections.java:54)
08-07 17:14:31.682: E/AndroidRuntime(2201):     at com.L00081183.mygpstool.MainActivity.onClick_GetDirections(MainActivity.java:145)
```

Comment: what is line 54 `MyGPSToolDirections.java`?

Comment: nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("step"); Sorry, I should have made that line clear!

Comment: It that there is no Document being returned by the getDocument method, it seems to execute these 4 line and gives up after.
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);

Comment: certain duplicate of [NullPointerException when using GMapsV2Direction class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18108630/nullpointerexception-when-using-gmapsv2direction-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I used to fetch Driving direction from Google Direction API. This uses JSON. May be this helps you.

This class constructs the query

```
public class DirectionAPI extends AbstractQuery {

    private static final String URL = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/";

    private static final boolean USE_SENSOR = true;

    /**
     * Required parameters
     */

    /**
     * Specifies the start location from which to calculate directions
     */
    private static final String PARAM_ORIGIN = "origin";

    /**
     * Specifies the end location to which to calculate directions.
     */
    private static final String PARAM_DESTINATION = "destination";

    /**
     * Indicates whether or not the directions request comes from a device with a location sensor.
     * This value must be either true or false
     */
    private static final String PARAM_SENSOR = "sensor";

    /**
     * Optional parameters
     */

    /**
     * Specifies what mode of transport to use when calculating directions
     */
    private static final String PARAM_TRAVEL_MODE = "mode";

    /**
     * Travel Modes
     */
    public static final String TRAVEL_MODE_DRIVING = "driving";
    public static final String TRAVEL_MODE_BICYCLING = "bicycling";
    public static final String TRAVEL_MODE_TRANSIT = "transit";
    public static final String TRAVEL_MODE_WALKING = "walking";

    /**
     * Specifies what unit system to use when displaying results
     */
    private static final String PARAM_UNIT_SYSTEM = "units";

    /**
     * Unit systems
     */
    public static final String UNIT_SYSTEM_METRIC = "metric";
    public static final String UNIT_SYSTEM_IMPERIAL = "imperial";

    /**
     *  Waypoints alter a route by routing it through the specified location(s)
     */
    private static final String PARAM_WAYPOINTS = "waypoints";

    /**
     * Specifies that the route using the supplied waypoints may be optimized to provide the
     * shortest possible route. If true, the Directions service will return the reordered
     * waypoints in an waypoint_order field
     */
    private static final String PARAM_OPTIMIZE_WAYPOINTS = "optimize";

    /**
     * When set to true specifies that the Directions service may provide more than one route
     * alternative in the response. Note that providing route alternatives may increase the
     * response time from the server
     */
    private static final String PARAM_PROVIDE_ROUTE_ALTERNATIVES = "alternatives";

    /**
     * Indicates that the calculated route(s) should avoid the indicated features.
     * Currently, this parameter supports the following two arguments:
     * tolls indicates that the calculated route should avoid toll roads/bridges.
     * highways indicates that the calculated route should avoid highways.
     */
    private static final String PARAM_AVOID = "avoid";

    private static final String AVOID_HIGHWAYS = "highways";
    private static final String AVOID_TOLLS = "tolls";

    /**
     * Specifies the region code, specified as a ccTLD ("top-level domain") two-character value
     * https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#DirectionsRegionBiasing
     */
    private static final String PARAM_REGION = "region";

    private LatLng origin;
    private LatLng destination;

    private Map<LatLng, Boolean> waypoints;
    private Map<String, String> optionalParams;

    public DirectionAPI(LatLng origin, LatLng destination) {
        if (origin == null || destination == null){
            throw new NullPointerException("Origin and destination should not be null");
        }
        this.origin = origin;
        this.destination = destination;
        optionalParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
        waypoints = new HashMap<LatLng, Boolean>();
    }

    public void addWaypoint(LatLng waypoint, boolean stopOver){
        waypoints.put(waypoint, stopOver);
    }

    public void removeWaypoint(LatLng waypoint){
        waypoints.remove(waypoint);
    }

    public void setTravelMode(String mode){
        optionalParams.put(PARAM_TRAVEL_MODE, mode);
    }

    public void setUnitSystem(String unitSystem){
        put(PARAM_UNIT_SYSTEM, unitSystem);
    }

    public void optimizeWaypoints(boolean optimize){
        put(PARAM_OPTIMIZE_WAYPOINTS, String.valueOf(optimize));
    }

    public void provideRouteAlternatives(boolean provide){
        put(PARAM_PROVIDE_ROUTE_ALTERNATIVES, String.valueOf(provide));
    }

    public void avoid(boolean highways, boolean tolls){
        if (!highways && !tolls){
            put(PARAM_AVOID, null);
        } else if (highways && !tolls){
            put(PARAM_AVOID, AVOID_HIGHWAYS);
        } else if (!highways){
            put(PARAM_AVOID, AVOID_TOLLS);
        } else {
            put(PARAM_AVOID, AVOID_TOLLS + "|" + AVOID_HIGHWAYS);
        }
    }

    public void setRegion(String region){
        put(PARAM_REGION, region);
    }

    private void put(String key, String value){
        if (value == null){
            optionalParams.remove(key);
        } else {
            optionalParams.put(key, value);
        }
    }

    public String constructQuery() {
        StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder(URL);
        query.append("json").append("?");
        query.append(PARAM_ORIGIN).append("=").append(origin.latitude).append(",").append(origin.longitude);
        query.append("&");
        query.append(PARAM_DESTINATION).append("=").append(destination.latitude).append(",").append(destination.longitude);
        query.append("&");
        query.append(PARAM_SENSOR).append("=").append(USE_SENSOR);
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : optionalParams.entrySet()){
            query.append("&");
            query.append(entry.getKey()).append("=").append(entry.getValue());
        }
        if (waypoints.size() > 0){
            query.append("&");
            query.append(PARAM_WAYPOINTS);
            for (Map.Entry<LatLng, Boolean> entry : waypoints.entrySet()){
                if (!entry.getValue()){
                    query.append("via:");
                }
                LatLng value = entry.getKey();
                query.append(value.latitude).append(",").append(value.longitude);
                query.append("|");
            }
            query.deleteCharAt(query.length()-1);
        }
        return query.toString();
    }

    public GoogleResponse execute(){
        GoogleResponse googleResponse;
        try {
            java.net.URL url = new URL(constructQuery());
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            if (httpURLConnection.getResponseCode() == 200){
                JSONObject jsonObject = JSONParser.parse(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());
                googleResponse = new GoogleResponse(jsonObject.getString("status"));
                if (googleResponse.isOk()){
                    googleResponse.setJsonObject(jsonObject);
                }
            } else {
                googleResponse = new GoogleResponse(httpURLConnection.getResponseCode());
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(Debug.TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
            googleResponse = new GoogleResponse(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(Debug.TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
            googleResponse = new GoogleResponse(e);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(Debug.TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
            googleResponse = new GoogleResponse(e);
        }
        return googleResponse;
    }

}
```

This class creates JSON object

```
public class JSONParser {

    public static JSONObject parse(InputStream inputStream){
        BufferedReader reader;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    inputStream, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line).append("\n");
            }
            inputStream.close();
            return new JSONObject(sb.toString());
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            Log.e(Debug.TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(Debug.TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(Debug.TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

This class reads the response status and check whether it is ok.

```
public class GoogleResponse {

    private static final String RESPONSE_OK = "OK";
    private static final String RESPONSE_ZERO_RESULT = "ZERO_RESULTS";
    private static final String RESPONSE_OVER_QUERY_LIMIT = "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT";
    private static final String RESPONSE_REQUEST_DENIED = "REQUEST_DENIED";
    private static final String RESPONSE_INVALID_REQUEST = "INVALID_REQUEST";

    public static final int OK = 0;
    public static final int ERROR_ZERO_RESULT = 10;
    public static final int ERROR_OVER_QUERY_LIMIT = 11;
    public static final int ERROR_REQUEST_DENIED = 12;
    public static final int ERROR_INVALID_REQUEST = 13;
    public static final int ERROR_UNKNOWN_RESPONSE = 14;

    public static final int ERROR_MALFORMED_URL = 15;
    public static final int ERROR_IO = 16;
    public static final int ERROR_JSON = 17;

    private int response = -1;
    private JSONObject jsonObject;

    public GoogleResponse(String response) {
        if (response.contentEquals(RESPONSE_OK)){
            this.response = OK;
        } else if (response.contentEquals(RESPONSE_ZERO_RESULT)){
            this.response = ERROR_ZERO_RESULT;
        } else if (response.contentEquals(RESPONSE_OVER_QUERY_LIMIT)){
            this.response = ERROR_OVER_QUERY_LIMIT;
        } else if (response.contentEquals(RESPONSE_REQUEST_DENIED)){
            this.response = ERROR_REQUEST_DENIED;
        } else if (response.contentEquals(RESPONSE_INVALID_REQUEST)){
            this.response = ERROR_INVALID_REQUEST;
        } else {
            Log.e(Debug.TAG, "Unknown response : " + response);
            this.response = ERROR_UNKNOWN_RESPONSE;
        }
    }

    public GoogleResponse(Exception e) {
        if (e instanceof MalformedURLException){
            response = ERROR_MALFORMED_URL;
        } else if (e instanceof IOException){
            response = ERROR_IO;
        } else if (e instanceof JSONException){
            response = ERROR_JSON;
        }
    }

    public GoogleResponse(int response) {
        this.response = response;
    }

    public int getResponse() {
        return response;
    }

    public boolean isOk(){
        return response < 10;
    }

    public JSONObject getJsonObject() {
        return jsonObject;
    }

    public void setJsonObject(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        this.jsonObject = jsonObject;
    }
}
```

This class parses the JSON data.

```
public class DrivingDirection {

    private static final String TAG_ROUTES = "routes";

    private static final String TAG_WAYPOINT_ORDER = "waypoint_order";
    private static final String TAG_SUMMARY = "summary";
    private static final String TAG_BOUNDS = "bounds";
    private static final String TAG_LEGS = "legs";
    private static final String TAG_WARNINGS = "warnings";
    private static final String TAG_OVERVIEW_POLYLINE = "overview_polyline";
    private static final String TAG_COPYRIGHTS = "copyrights";
    private static final String TAG_BOUND_NORTH_EAST = "northeast";
    private static final String TAG_BOUND_SOUTH_WEST = "southwest";

    private String summary;
    private String copyrights;
    private ArrayList<LatLng> overviewPolyline;
    private ArrayList<LatLng> smoothPolyline;

    private JSONArray warnings;
    private JSONArray waypointOrder;

    private LatLng boundNorthEast;
    private LatLng boundSouthWest;

    private ArrayList<DirectionLeg> directionLegs;

    private String json;

    public DrivingDirection(JSONObject response) {
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray(TAG_ROUTES);
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
            summary = jsonObject.getString(TAG_SUMMARY);
            copyrights = jsonObject.getString(TAG_COPYRIGHTS);
            overviewPolyline = decodePolyline(jsonObject.getJSONObject(TAG_OVERVIEW_POLYLINE).getString("points"));
            warnings = jsonObject.getJSONArray(TAG_WARNINGS);
            waypointOrder = jsonObject.getJSONArray(TAG_WAYPOINT_ORDER);
            JSONObject bounds = jsonObject.getJSONObject(TAG_BOUNDS);
            boundNorthEast = interpretLatLng(bounds.getJSONObject(TAG_BOUND_NORTH_EAST));
            boundSouthWest = interpretLatLng(bounds.getJSONObject(TAG_BOUND_SOUTH_WEST));
            JSONArray legs = jsonObject.getJSONArray(TAG_LEGS);
            directionLegs = new ArrayList<DirectionLeg>(legs.length());
            for (int i=0; i<legs.length(); i++){
                directionLegs.add(new DirectionLeg(legs.getJSONObject(i)));
            }
            json = response.toString();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(Debug.TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    public String getSummary() {
        return summary;
    }

    public String getCopyrights() {
        return copyrights;
    }

    public ArrayList<LatLng> getOverviewPolyline() {
        return overviewPolyline;
    }

    public ArrayList<LatLng> getTotalPolyline(){
        if (smoothPolyline == null) {
            smoothPolyline = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
            for (DirectionLeg directionLeg : directionLegs){
                for (DirectionStep directionStep : directionLeg.getDirectionSteps()){
                    smoothPolyline.addAll(directionStep.getPolyline());
                }
            }
        }
        return smoothPolyline;
    }

    public JSONArray getWarnings() {
        return warnings;
    }

    public JSONArray getWaypointOrder() {
        return waypointOrder;
    }

    public LatLng getBoundNorthEast() {
        return boundNorthEast;
    }

    public LatLng getBoundSouthWest() {
        return boundSouthWest;
    }

    public ArrayList<DirectionLeg> getDirectionLegs() {
        return directionLegs;
    }

    public long getDistance(){
        long distance = 0L;
        for (DirectionLeg directionLeg : directionLegs){
            distance += directionLeg.getDistance();
        }
        return distance;
    }

    public long getDuration(){
        long duration = 0L;
        for (DirectionLeg directionLeg : directionLegs){
            duration += directionLeg.getDuration();
        }
        return duration;
    }

    public void addPolyline(Polyline polyline){
        polyline.setPoints(this.overviewPolyline);
    }

    public static ArrayList<LatLng> decodePolyline(String encoded) {
        ArrayList<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
        int lat = 0, lng = 0;
        while (index < len) {
            int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;
            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;
            LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
                    (((double) lng / 1E5)));
            poly.add(p);
        }
        return poly;
    }

    private static LatLng interpretLatLng(JSONObject object){
        try {
            return new LatLng(object.getDouble("lat"), object.getDouble("lng"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(Debug.TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public String getJson() {
        return json;
    }

    public static class DirectionLeg {

        private long duration;
        private long distance;
        private LatLng startLocation;
        private LatLng endLocation;
        private String startAddress;
        private String endAddress;
        private JSONArray viaWaypoints;
        private ArrayList<DirectionStep> directionSteps;

        public DirectionLeg(JSONObject jsonObject) {
            try {
                distance = jsonObject.getJSONObject("distance").getLong("value");
                duration = jsonObject.getJSONObject("duration").getLong("value");
                startAddress = jsonObject.getString("start_address");
                endAddress = jsonObject.getString("end_address");
                viaWaypoints = jsonObject.getJSONArray("via_waypoint");
                startLocation = DrivingDirection.interpretLatLng(jsonObject.getJSONObject("start_location"));
                endLocation = DrivingDirection.interpretLatLng(jsonObject.getJSONObject("end_location"));
                JSONArray steps = jsonObject.getJSONArray("steps");
                directionSteps = new ArrayList<DirectionStep>(steps.length());
                for (int i=0; i<steps.length(); i++){
                    directionSteps.add(new DirectionStep(steps.getJSONObject(i)));
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e(Debug.TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }

        public long getDuration() {
            return duration;
        }

        public long getDistance() {
            return distance;
        }

        public LatLng getStartLocation() {
            return startLocation;
        }

        public LatLng getEndLocation() {
            return endLocation;
        }

        public String getStartAddress() {
            return startAddress;
        }

        public String getEndAddress() {
            return endAddress;
        }

        public JSONArray getViaWaypoints() {
            return viaWaypoints;
        }

        public ArrayList<DirectionStep> getDirectionSteps() {
            return directionSteps;
        }
    }

    public static class DirectionStep{

        private String htmlInstruction;
        private long duration;
        private long distance;
        private LatLng startLocation;
        private LatLng endLocation;
        private String travelMode;
        private String polyline;
        private ArrayList<LatLng> polylinePoints;

        public DirectionStep(JSONObject jsonObject){
            try {
                htmlInstruction = jsonObject.getString("html_instructions");
                duration = jsonObject.getJSONObject("duration").getLong("value");
                distance = jsonObject.getJSONObject("distance").getLong("value");
                JSONObject startLocation = jsonObject.getJSONObject("start_location");
                this.startLocation = new LatLng(startLocation.getDouble("lat"), startLocation.getDouble("lng"));
                JSONObject endLocation = jsonObject.getJSONObject("end_location");
                this.endLocation = new LatLng(endLocation.getDouble("lat"), endLocation.getDouble("lng"));
                travelMode = jsonObject.getString("travel_mode");
                polyline = jsonObject.getJSONObject("polyline").getString("points");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e(Debug.TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }

        public String getHtmlInstruction() {
            return htmlInstruction;
        }

        public long getDuration() {
            return duration;
        }

        public long getDistance() {
            return distance;
        }

        public LatLng getStartLocation() {
            return startLocation;
        }

        public LatLng getEndLocation() {
            return endLocation;
        }

        public String getTravelMode() {
            return travelMode;
        }

        public ArrayList<LatLng> getPolyline() {
            if (polylinePoints == null){
                polylinePoints = decodePolyline(polyline);
            }
            return polylinePoints;
        }
    }

}
```

Typical usage. If you want you can set optional parameters like waypoints etc.

```
    LatLng start = new LatLng(1.11, 1.11);
    LatLng end = new LatLng(2.22, 2.22);
    DirectionAPI directionAPI = new DirectionAPI(start, end);
    GoogleResponse googleResponse = directionAPI.execute();
    if (googleResponse.isOk()){
        DrivingDirection drivingDirection =  new DrivingDirection(googleResponse.getJsonObject());
        ArrayList<LatLng> polyline = drivingDirection.getTotalPolyline();
    }
```